# Sending a foreign key to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Client model with the following properties:

- Id (PK)
- Name
- Balance

And a Payment model with the following properties:

- Id (PK)
- Date
- Amount
- ClientId (FK)

In my Client's `Index` method, I just display a list of clients. Next to each client, there is the usual `View`, `Edit`, `Delete` option, but I also added `Add Payment`, which calls the `Create` method from the `Payment` controller and sends the `ClientId` as parameter:

`@Html.ActionLink("Add payment", "Create","Payment", new { id = item.Id },null)`

Now comes the problem. How do I make the payment's Create method receive that `ClientId` integer and pass it onto the model so that I don't have to manually select the `ClientId` again in the Payment/Create method's view.

[image]

I know how to remove the dropdown list from the View, but it then just sends 0 as the ClientId by default. I want it to use the ClientId that I sent it when clicking on the "Add payment" actionlink in the Client's Index View.

My methods for the create payment are the default generated ones:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ClientId = new SelectList(db.Clients, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Date,Amount,ClientId")] Payment payment, int id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Payments.Add(payment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ClientId = new SelectList(db.Clients, "Id", "Name", payment.ClientId);
        return View(payment);
    }
```

When I add "int Id" as a parameter to the first create method, I just get a bunch of errors. I'm just clueless and haven't found any resources helping with my problem. Any help is appreciated (even if it's a link that could guide me in the right direction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the `ClientId` to the Model and store in a HiddenField, you can use the same `Payment` class:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Payment payment = new Payment();
        payment.ClientId = 394;
        return View(payment);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Payment payment)
    {
        //Payment.ClientId will be available here
        return View();
    }
```

and in the View:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Payment
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Pay", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.ClientId);
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
}
```